# Skew background with Gimp

Tags: gimp, transparency, skew

I have a logo which is skewed and would like to skew the background to match without further skewing the logo.
[image]
The image on the left is what I currently have, the skewed rounded rectangle with the box inside represent the logo. On the right is what I need with the lighter gray representing transparency.

In addition, the background should also get a border radius to match the logo border radius. So I would end up with the following:

[image]

How can I add transparency to the background in such a way to achieve this result using Gimp? I thought of adding a transparent layer and skewing the first layer but that would result in the already skewed logo inside becoming more skewed. I just want the angle of the background to match the logo.

Comment: Honestly the current logo doesn't look good, the lines are already pixelated and the round shapes don't look regular. It is also likely too small. You can do better in Gimp, but the right tool for this is Inkscape (Inkscape creates [vector graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics), these can be rescaled at will without quality loss).

Comment: Do you also want to make visible all the background details  which are now covered by the main object but which must show up when the  background is skewed? A trick which does it would be especially valuable at least if the image has only a single layer.

Comment: To clarify, the images are for illustrative purposes only, not the actual logo I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to skew the background, just recreate it.

- Erase most of the background around the existing skewed rectangle (no need  to be too accurate)
- Using the Rectangle select, create a rectangle selection mask with rounded corners:

[image]

- Then use the Shear tool in "Transform:Selection" mode (this is the red square icon in the "Transform" line) to skew the selection mask:

[image]

- Then add a layer and bucket-fill the selection wit the color of the curent background

[image]

- Move the layer under your initial layer